# convert hours into seconds in R

Tags: r

I have data in format of hours and need to turn everything into seconds . Can anyone help me ?

2:00:00 3:00:00 6:00:00 4:00:00 4:00:00 3:00:48 1:00:00 3:00:00 2:00:00
 4:00:00 1:30:00 2:00:00 1:00:00 3:00:00 4:00:00 4:30:00 5:00:00

Comment: I know . But I need to do this for all hours in my bunch of data in R

Comment: If anyone has another idea of how to do , please post there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Read the data in
x <- unlist(strsplit("2:00:00 3:00:00 6:00:00 4:00:00 4:00:00 3:00:48 1:00:00 3:00:00 2:00:00 4:00:00 1:30:00 2:00:00 1:00:00 3:00:00 4:00:00 4:30:00 5:00:00", "[[:space:]]+"))
x
# [1] "2:00:00" "3:00:00" "6:00:00" "4:00:00" "4:00:00" "3:00:48" "1:00:00"
# [8] "3:00:00" "2:00:00" "4:00:00" "1:30:00" "2:00:00" "1:00:00" "3:00:00"
#[15] "4:00:00" "4:30:00" "5:00:00"
```

Split each string on the `:`.  Multiply the first number by 3600, the second by 60, and the last by 1.  Then add them up.  This can be done with matrix multiplication in one step.

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), function(n) as.numeric(n) %*% c(3600, 60, 1))
# [1]  7200 10800 21600 14400 14400 10848  3600 10800  7200 14400  5400  7200
#[13]  3600 10800 14400 16200 18000
```

---

Alternatively, you could convert the times to proper `POSIXct` objects and subtract midnight from them to get the number of seconds

```
as.numeric(strptime(x, format="%H:%M:%S") - as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date())), units="secs")
# [1]  7200 10800 21600 14400 14400 10848  3600 10800  7200 14400  5400  7200
#[13]  3600 10800 14400 16200 18000
```

Answer (score 1):

The `qdapTools` library has the `hms2sec` function to do this:

```
x <- unlist(strsplit("2:00:00 3:00:00 6:00:00 4:00:00 4:00:00 3:00:48 1:00:00 3:00:00 2:00:00 4:00:00 1:30:00 2:00:00 1:00:00 3:00:00 4:00:00 4:30:00 5:00:00", "[[:space:]]+"))
x

library(qdapTools)
hms2sec(x)

##  [1]  7200 10800 21600 14400 14400 10848  3600 10800  7200
## [10] 14400  5400  7200  3600 10800 14400 16200 18000
```